# How to Change Highlighted Items Color in Alfresco Share Form

Tags: javascript, css, workflow, share, alfresco

so I have been trying to change the highlight color in which documents show up in the "items" field within an Alfresco Share workflow form. Basically, given a starting form that looks like this...

[image]

You will notice that every other document that gets added to the items field is automatically highlighted light blue. I was wondering if it was possible to change that color, and furthermore if it was possible to set it so only the top item (or a single items) gets highlighted in that list of documents?

I thought this would be as simple as finding and changing a CSS file somewhere, but despite changing a number of different CSS files within Alfresco, I have had little luck changing that color. Just wondering if anyone had any experience with this and would be willing to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:
The class you're looking for is:

tr.yui-dt-highlighted

The problem here is that these classes are generated automatically by JavaScript injected in the page. So, I've searched and found this little info:
path `share/res/js/yui-common.js` you should use a tool like [JavaScript Formatting](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to understand some code in there. There is a CLASS_HIGHLIGHTED that starts a function, and you should try to override this:

```
highlightRow: function (k) {
    var i = this.getTrEl(k);
    if (i) {
        var j = this.getRecord(i);
        c.addClass(i, d.CLASS_HIGHLIGHTED);
        this.fireEvent("rowHighlightEvent", {
            record: j,
            el: i
        });
        return;
    }
},
unhighlightRow: function (k) {
    var i = this.getTrEl(k);
    if (i) {
        var j = this.getRecord(i);
        c.removeClass(i, d.CLASS_HIGHLIGHTED);
        this.fireEvent("rowUnhighlightEvent", {
            record: j,
            el: i
        });
        return;
    }
},
```

There are highlightRow and highlightColumn to look into. It's always very difficult to override YAHOO yui functions..

Comment: Thanks for the help! But after looking at the source code on the workflow page, I was able to deduce that it was actually the `/share/yui/assets/skins/default/skin.css` file I needed to change in order to highlight color. So now I can change the highlighted color of every "odd" item, but I'm working on trying to figure out how to change just the first item in the list. And I looked in `packageitems.ftl`, but I didn't see anything in the code related to the view/color/etc?